# How to get SUM of the values of comma separated variables and the variable count in a single spreadsheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get the SUM of the values of comma separated variables (Issued Items) in `Google Sheet`. Please see the table below;

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
|   Issued Items        |   SUM     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
|   A-22, A-22, B-11    |   120     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
|   C-33, 11, 22-X      |   160     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
|   22-X, D-54, 22      |   110     |
+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Edited: The `Values` for each `Item` will be stored in another sheet. And how can I get the count of `Issued items`?

Please note that the `Items` may repeat in a single cell and may also have prefix and suffix which are needed to be counted as individuals.

```
+-----------------------+-------+
|   Items   |   Values  |   QTY |   
+-----------------------+-------+
|   A-22    |   50      |   2   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   B-11    |   20      |   1   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   C-33    |   70      |   1   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   D-54    |   40      |   1   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   11      |   30      |   1   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   22      |   10      |   1   |
+-----------------------+-------+
|   22-X    |   60      |   2   |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

It would save a lot of time and effort for me.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(D2, ", ")), A:B, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
={"QTY"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A),
  QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, D2:D), ", ")),
  "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0)))}
```

[image: 0]